# Pandas GroupBy on column names

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, we can proxy by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0], 'b':[0,1,0], 'c':[1,0,0], 'd':[2,3,4]})
```

and a category series

```
category = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I'd like to get a sum of df's columns grouped into the categories 'A', 'B'.  Maybe something like:

```
result = df.groupby(??, axis=1).sum()
```

returning

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,3,4], 'B':[1,1,0]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `sum` on the columns (the `axis=1` is important here):

```
df.groupby(df.columns.map(category.get), axis=1).sum()

   A  B
0  3  1
1  3  1
2  4  0
```

Answer (score 3):

After `reindex` you can assign the category to the column of df

```
df=df.reindex(columns=category.index)
df.columns=category
df.groupby(df.columns.values,axis=1).sum()
Out[1255]: 
   A  B
0  3  1
1  3  1
2  4  0
```

Or `pd.Series.get`

```
df.groupby(category.get(df.columns),axis=1).sum()
Out[1262]: 
   A  B
0  3  1
1  3  1
2  4  0
```

Comment: It's better to map columns to categories (example, in my answer). The opposite might not work if categories has a different size, or if it contains invalid mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i did to group dataframe with similar column names

data_df:

```
1    1    2   1

q    r   f    t
```

Code:

```
df_grouped = data_df.groupby(data_df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.values))
```

df_grouped:

```
1       2
q r t   f
```